# Usage of "Amen to [something]"

Tags: idioms

Does the phrase "Amen to some common sense" in the below example have a positive or negative connotation?

> "Students will gain that eligibility automatically; amen to some common sense."

Comment: I (a US English speaker) think this use of *amen* is very strange-sounding.  It's clear that the speaker means "thanks to some common sense", but it's not how we usually use *amen*.  "Amen to that" is a very stock phrase, but any variation sounds weird.

Answer (score 1):

It has a positive connotation.  "Amen!" is said after Christian prayers, and is used positively.

The second meaning from the [OLD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/amen) is what you are looking for:

> (figurative)
> Amen **to that** (I certainly agree with that).

**It has the effect of roughly equating to "Thank God!"**

So the sentence you asked about ("Amen to some common sense!") would roughly translate to "Thank God for some common sense!".

Comment: As your link tells us, it means "Let it be so", not "Thank God".

Comment: In order to fit the sentence I'm referring more to the second meaning given, not the first one — though you are also correct.  The "Thank God" is a rough equation in order to make it easy to understand in that context.

Comment: "Some common sense has been applied, and we heartily endorse that."

Comment: Be careful, though, It's very positive to the thing being responded to. So much so that it can suggest exasperation or disappointment with what was going on before!

So If your boss says "let's do X", and your colleague says "let's do Y", don't say "Amen to some common sense", or you will be in trouble, :-D .

Answer (score 0):

"Amen" is derived from a [hebrew word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amen) אָמֵן, ʾāmēn : it is an affirmation. It is said at the end of formal Christian prayers, to affirm that you believe that the prayer is true.

When used in the expression "Amen to ...", the meaning is only tangentially related to the original meaning: you are suggesting that your prayers have been answered. It is usually used when a practice that you disapprove of strongly has been, or is about to be, discontinued.

It should therefore be seen as a criticism of whatever practice has ended, rather than an approval of what is about to start happening.

In the particular example that you quoted, the speaker is suggesting that they disagreed strongly with the previous eligibility requirements. Adding the reference to common sense further strengthens the implication that what went before was stupid.

Answer (score 0):

The word "amen" comes from a Hebrew word meaning "truth". Thus, it is used to indicate agreement with something just said. In the US, most commonly in a Christian context. Like in some more boisterous churches, if the preacher says something you agree with, you shout "Amen, preacher!"

In the US, it is most commonly used by Christians as a kind of logout from a prayer. Like, "God, we praise you, and we ask that you do thus-and-so for us. Amen." Christians routinely define it as meaning "so be it" in this context.

"Amen to that" is a common idiom, outside the religious context, meaning "yes, that's true", and is thus essentially the first definition I gave above. For example, someone says, "Wow, inflation is really high this year" and someone else says "Amen to that".

Your example is in the same category. "Students will gain eligibility automatically. Amen to common sense." Apparently the writer believes that students gaining eligibility automatically is a good, common-sense idea. So this is probably a positive statement.

Without having the larger context I can't say if the statement is made literally or ironically. It sounds literal from the excerpt, but irony is possible. Like if someone makes a suggestion that you think is really stupid, you might ironically say, "Wow, that's a brilliant idea." If spoken, your tone of voice will indicate you don't really mean it. If written, that would have to be made clear by context. So it's POSSIBLE that the writer here means this ironically. I don't know.